# How can I do a bi-directional Port-Forwarding (flow encapsulation)?

Tags: port-forwarding, port, tcp, windows-server

I have two applications: a **client** and a **server** which communicate through port **1234**. For some reasons this port is blocked on our system but everything works correctly on port **1235** (checked with two simple C++ Client/Server applications)

Can I do a bi-directional port forwarding as shown in the figure below:

[image: bi-directional Port-Forwarding]

I want to know if it would be possible to encapsulate all the stream from port 1234 into one stream on port 1235.

**Informations**:

- **OS**: Windows Server 2008 (Client and Server machine)
- **Access rights**: Administrator (Client and Server Machine)

Comment: yes, this should be doable, provided there are routers on each end that you can configure. you could even do it on the LAN just using ssh tunneling. TCP\1234 has historically been used by many malware strains, including W32\Beagle, so that is likely why its blocked. personally I'd pick a port a bit higher, like between 5000 and 10000, because OSes commonly assign ports sequentially starting at 1024 for adhoc client connections, but that's just a matter of readability.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for this information. I will investigate

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you. Suggested modification done.

Comment: Kinda [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). The most elegant solution is to unblock the port. As an administrator you should be able to do this, unless the port is blocked somewhere in between. Or you may be able to reconfigure the client and the server software to use another port. Please confirm you have truly considered and rejected these ideas.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski network administrators don't want to touch the network configuration. reason why I'm here ...